# Executing java from python program

Tags: java, python-3.x

```
import os.path, subprocess
from subprocess import STDOUT, PIPE

def compile_java (java_file):
    subprocess.check_call(['javac', java_file])

def execute_java (java_file):
    cmd=['java', java_file]
    proc=subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout = PIPE, stderr = STDOUT)
    input = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin = PIPE)
    print(proc.stdout.read())

compile_java("D:\\GFG.java")
execute_java("D:\\GFG")
```

The above code is compiling but at `execute_java("D:\\GFG")`

> Error: Could not find or load main class GFG\r\n'.

Please help

Comment: Aren't you appending \r\n to the string?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have `GDG.class` file in `D:\`, the command to execute the java program is

```
java -cp D:\ GFG
```

This means: 'execute a java program, main class is `GFG`; `D:\` directory is on classpath'.

`java` will load your program classes from `D:\`, will try to find `GFG` class and execute its `main()` method.

Instead, you execute the following:

```
java D:\GFG
```

which is interpreted as 'execute code in class `D:\GFG`' which does not make sense.